# Property of Perron root of non-negative matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let's have

$A_{1}=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 3 & 0 & 1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}\,$$A_{2}=\begin{bmatrix}3 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 2 & 1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 4 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 4
\end{bmatrix}$

For both matrices, $\min\, rowsum(A_{1})=\min\, rowsum(A_{2}),$ $\max\, rowsum(A_{1})=\max\, rowsum(A_{2}),$
$trace\left(A_{1}\right)=trace\left(A_{2}\right),$ $\max\left(A_{1}\right)_{ij}=\max\left(A_{2}\right)_{ij}$,
so what properties of non negative matrix we can use to prove that
$\rho\left(A_{2}\right)>\rho\left(A_{1}\right)?$ $\rho\left(.\right)$
denotes for spectral radius, i,e, perron root in this case.

Thanks for any helps.